# remove double quotes from field

Tags: php, regex, csv, fgetcsv

Here is the current format of the csv file I am parsing

```
"Street","City","Country"
"House # 3, Street "23, H, Block". Building 32", "CityName", "Country"
```

Here you can see that `23, H, Block` is surrounded by double quotation marks and commas in them - when I am parsing this file using the code below

```
while (! feof($file)) {
    // provide last parameter so in case we get \ in a field it 
    // doesn't break the data
    $row = fgetcsv($file, null, ",", '"', '"');
    // so we don't send anything besides array
    if (count($row) > 0) {
        // if array is empty we don't pass it to further proceeding
        if ($row) {
            $sorted[] = array_merge($rows, $row);
        }
    }
}
```

The parsing divides `23`, `h` and `Block` into different elements while they should be one

This is what happens

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Street"
    1 => "City"
    2 => "Country"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    0 => "House # 3, Street 23"
    1 => " H"
    2 => " Block". Building 32""
    3 => "CityName"
    4 => "Country"
  ]
]
```

While I want it like this

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Street"
    1 => "City"
    2 => "Country"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "House # 3, Street 23, H, Block. Building 32"
    1 => "CityName"
    2 => "Country"
  ]
]
```

If I can have some regex pattern to remove the unwanted quotation mark from the whole csv file it would be helpful

Comment: If you have quotes inside a field, they need to be escaped. Fix the program that creates the file.

Comment: oops, I am not creating the file so I am trying to find a hack to have this done - something like ```file_get_content()``` find the extra quote remove them then using ```file_put_content()``` rewrite the file and then parse it

Comment: You could use a regular expression to match quotes that aren't next to a comma or the beginning/end of the line, and remove them.

Comment: yes that's why I said ```If I can have some regex pattern to remove the unwanted quotation mark from the whole csv file it would be helpful```

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/Cnkf1G) based on a `\B"\b((?:[^"]*|(?R))*)\b"\B` regex. It is actually not hard *if* your quotes are really enclosed with word boundaries/non-word boundaries. Else, it will be just impossible.

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure about the solution, regex is which I could think of - I am hoping to have something better for this problem because regex are not absolute and I have tried writing regex but the best I could write was not able to help me if you can help then let me share that with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should focus on how to correctly split the line/row into tokens instead of removing unwanted double-quote characters from the line.

The block delimiter has form of `","` or `", "` thus the regex to split the line would be

```
(?<="),\s*(?=")
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Q5yqXM/4) with regex explanation